How to make a image taller than content in a grid container?
I'm working on a grid layout that displays recent articles. Each article has an image and a short description. I want the image to be taller than the content text block, and still maintain responsiveness across different screen sizes.
Here's the relevant part of my code using tailwind css and next js:

<div className="grid gap-2">
    {articles.recentArticles.map((article, index) => (
        <Link className="block rounded-lg overflow-hidden" key={index} href={`/article/${article.urlSlug}`}>
            <div className="p-4 flex items-center justify-center"> { }
                <Image
                    src={article.image.url}
                    alt={article.title}
                    width={150}
                    height={500} className="h-500 w-150 rounded-md mr-4"
                />

                <div className="space-y-2 flex-grow">
                    <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-2">{article.title}</h2>
                    <p className="text-gray-600 mb-4 line-clamp-2">{article.description}</p>
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                        <p className="text-gray-600">{formatDate(article.createdAt)}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </Link>
    ))}
</div>

What i actually want is something similar to this

I've tried Setting a fixed height for the image element, but nothing works.
I'm hoping to achieve a responsive layout where the image is always taller than the content text block.

varies, but in most cases the image are wider, and square, they are not generally taller.

I don’t see how it’s geometrically possible to achieve this given  any random viewport width and any random text  - as you increase the height of the image so the width available for text decreases and so its height increases….

seems like a valid concern, so how do i structured this div?

It's easy enough if you're willing to have part of the image not displayed at certain screen sizes.

@ralph.m ‘s suggestion is the only possibility.

i am stuck on how to approach this. i can only think of removing the description from the text content..

Add the property ObjectFit="contain" to the <Image/>.

@Rasik You can’t achieve it in the general case.

@AHaworth so any workaround do you suggest? i tested width different title length, the image does not appear properly...

I don’t know what compromises you are able to make. Is it more important that all the image shows or that it is higher than the text?

i think it is not important at all.. honestly i didn't come to that thinking any logically, it just came out because i thought it would look nice. .not any heuristic..

I see 3 options.

Increase an image's width. As you increase the width, its height will grow inevitably, proportionally. Although the text part (title and description on the right) will contain less characters as its width will be shrinked.
Play around with font properties: make the font size smaller, force the title to take only one line, reduce gaps. Be careful not to make the whole thing hard to read though. But take a look at your example: the font there is really small.
object-fit magic. This option would only work if you don't care about keeping the image proportions. If you're okay with a square or vertical rectangle shape of the illustration, you may set whatever width/height you like and then add the object-fit: cover property: it makes an image to behave like a background, cropping what doesn't fit your custom size without distorting the picture itself.

Note: I work with vanilla CSS, so not sure about the Tailwind syntax.
And here is a fiddle of how it works with plain HTML+CSS.
Hope it helps!
